# Where am I going wrong? Trying to output average with awk

Tags: awk, average

I am taking the following data and trying to output the average with awk.

```
$ cat chores.csv
Chore Name,Assigned to,estimate,done?
Laundry,Chelsey,45,N
Wash Windows,Sam,60,Y
Mop kitchen,Sam,20,N
Clean cookware,Chelsey,30,N
Unload dishwasher,Chelsey,10,N
Dust living room,Chelsey,20,N
Wash the dog,Sam,40,N
```

Here is the script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/awk

BEGIN {
NR>1
FS=","
} $3 > 0 {
i++ ; tot+=$3
avg=tot/i
}
END{
printf "\nAverage: %.2f\n ", avg
}
```

When I run it, I get an incorrect output

```
awk -f avg.awk chores.csv

Average: 28.12
```

The answer should be `32.14`

Comment: Add debugging prints, especially at the end `print "tot="tot "\ti=" i`. Worst case is to add debugging in the main loop. Good luck.

Comment: Only the conditions _immediately before a block_ gate whether that block is run. When you put `NR>1` in the `BEGIN` instead of before the `{ i++; tot+=$3 }`, you stop it from having any use.

Comment: BTW, think of computing `avg` in the END block so you're doing it only once instead of over and over for every line..

Comment: Once you get an answer to the question you asked, make sure to add a test for `i` being non-zero before you try to divide by it, e.g. `print (i ? tot/i : 0)` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

You are counting the header line, even though it doesn't have the number you want.

Change to:

```
#!/bin/awk

BEGIN {
    FS=","
} 
NR > 1 && $3 > 0 {  # NR > 1 check moved here
    i++; 
    tot += $3
}
END {
    avg=tot/i
    printf "\nAverage: %.2f\n ", avg
}
```

This also removes the `NR > 1` from the `BEGIN` block, where it's not needed, and calculates the average only once, in the `END`, instead of for each row, as you're only printing that in the end anyway. Makes the code a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt at screening out the header line clearly isn't working. An obvious possibility would be something on this general order (untested, but simple enough I'd expect it to work anyway):

```
$3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/    {
        i++;
        tot+=$3;
        avg=tot/i;
    }
```

Personally, I'd probably compute `avg` only once, in the `END` clause though. It's not clear to me what the `NR>1` is intended to do. Maybe you intended it to be part of a pattern instead of an action? And even with a trivial awk script, it's worth the trouble to indent decently, so the script would looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/awk

BEGIN {
        FS=","
    }

$3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/    {
        i++ ;
        tot+=$3
    }

END{
    avg=tot/i
    printf "\nAverage: %.2f\n ", avg
}
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Although "apparently" is often used to mean something like "probably", I'm using its real meaning, so this sentence is essentially equivalent to: "It is apparent that your attempt at screening out the header line isn't working."

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I guess--I've edited to strengthen the statement a bit. Not sure it makes a big difference, but I guess it doesn't hurt anything, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the script for another answer:

```
awk -F, '$3 > 0  { i++; tot += $3 }  END { printf "\nAverage: %.2f\n ", tot/(i-1) }'
```

You do not need in `gawk` to skip first line, it is interpreted as `0`. Also division can be added in `printf` command.

Also IMHO estimate column can be zero, but can't be negative so you can skip the check and also not required to use counter (variable `i`). So the script ca become even sampler

```
awk -F, '{  tot += $3 }  END { printf "\nAverage: %.2f\n ", tot/(NR-1) }'
```

Comment: Those versions aren't equivalent. The second script includes 0s in the average while the first one didn't. Granted, there are no 0s in the example data, but that doesn't mean they can't occur.

Comment: @MaksVerver, correct. The OP do not mention about zeroes, so I just add example in this direction :)